# My keyboard is not working. How do I get back keyboard driver back?

Tags: drivers, keyboard, 18.04, onscreen-keyboard

My keyboard is not working. I believe I might have accidentally removed keyboard driver. On turning my laptop on, I get password screen. How do I get back keyboard driver back? I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: This is kindof dumb, but you could just try update all your xorg packages `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`. For the time being, you could also try plugging in an external keyboard, or use the on-screen one.

Comment: I have tried external keyboard, but it is also not working. The on-screen keyboard is also not coming .

Comment: Solved it finally .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solved it**

- Start Ubuntu on recovery mode. (Hold shift when turn on your PC, go to advance option, select recovery mode, I selected last one)
- Enable network. (Make sure you connected your Laptop with Ethernet cable)
- Go to the command from root option (on recovery mode option)
  Type (as mentioned in comment by @binamenator):

  `apt install xserver-xorg-input-all`
- Your keyboard drive will be installed.
- Reboot your laptop
  `reboot`