# Loading manually-installed firmware on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: kernel, firmware

##### Summary

I'm trying to replace a small number of firmware binaries with newer versions that [fix a bug](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/20240202.git36777504-0ubuntu1) affecting my hardware.  I've followed a procedure that should load the new firmware, but it doesn't seem to do that. How can I load the new firmware?

*Updating the `linux-firmware` package to the version under development for 24.04 (Noble Numbat) [might also be](https://community.frame.work/t/responded-wi-fi-dropping-on-fw-13-w-ubuntu-amd/44732/6) an acceptable solution. If this is feasible, I can ask a new question about how to do it.*

##### System details

- **OS:** Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy Jellyfish)
- **Kernel:** 6.5.0-15-generic #15~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC
- **Secure boot:** on

##### Firmware loading procedure

Here's the firmware update procedure I tried (with the goal of solving [this problem](https://community.frame.work/t/responded-wi-fi-dropping-on-fw-13-w-ubuntu-amd/44732/3)):

1. Move the default binaries out of their directory.

   - The [specific binaries](https://community.frame.work/t/responded-wi-fi-dropping-on-fw-13-w-ubuntu-amd/44732/32) are:

     ```
     /lib/firmware/mediatek/BT_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1_2_hdr.bin
     /lib/firmware/mediatek/WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
     /lib/firmware/mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1.bin
     ```
2. Replace the removed binaries with newer versions.
3. Call `sudo update-initramfs -u` to regenerate the initial RAM disk.
4. Reboot.

##### Unexpected outcome

I don't think the new binaries are running. Here's why.

- The build times in the `dmesg` logs from the relevant kernel module haven't changed:

  ```
  [    2.302579] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  [    2.311065] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: ASIC revision: 79220010
  [    2.399380] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: HW/SW Version: 0x8a108a10, Build Time: 20221227123154a
  [    2.778037] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0: WM Firmware Version: ____000000, Build Time: 20221227123243
  [    3.867760] mt7921e 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
  ```
- The `srcversion` number in the relevant `modinfo` output (`modinfo mt7921e`) hasn't changed—although I'm not sure it would change if the new firmware loaded, because it doesn't seem to come from the replaced binaries.

  ```
  filename:       /lib/modules/6.5.0-15-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/mediatek/mt76/mt7921/mt7921e.ko
  ```

  ⋮

  ```
  firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin
  firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin
  firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_MT7961_patch_mcu_1_2_hdr.bin
  firmware:       mediatek/WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7961_1.bin
  srcversion:     6691EA96F8FB6412FC35FFB
  ```
- I haven't noticed any change in how the hardware behaves.

##### Troubleshooting checks

- The new binaries are different from the old ones, but have the same names (checked with `diff`).
- The permissions of the old and new binaries match.
- The modification date of the initial RAM disk I'm booting from (`/boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-15-generic`) matches the last time I ran `update-initramfs`.
- Following a suggestion by @DanielT, I tried skipping step 2 in the procedure, which should leave the `mt7921e` module missing some of its firmware. This still doesn't affect the `dmesg` output or hardware behavior (although it does change the `modprobe` output).

Comment: You're running `srcversion` on the `.ko` files, which are separate from the firmware files. It may be better to use `cmp` or `sha256sum` instead of `diff`. I think the new binaries are running. If you're still in doubt, delete them, update-initramfs, reboot, see errors in `dmesg`, put them back, update-initramfs, reboot, see no more errors

Comment: @DanielT, would the `dmesg` errors also include the string `mt7921e`?

Comment: I don't know whether it will contain any specific string. All I know is that the `WM Firmware Version` line will change to something else

Comment: @DanielT, all right. Should trying to boot without this firmware (for the kernel module `mt7921e`) have any effect other than stopping my wireless card from working?

Comment: No, missing firmware problems are localized to the affected devices. Firmware for new computers are frequently missing, but those computers did not explode

Comment: @DanielT, although I've never heard of a broken kernel module making a device explode, I have heard of it stopping the [keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1049922/my-keyboard-is-not-working-how-do-i-get-back-keyboard-driver-back) or [screen](https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-my-laptops-screen-is-blank-but-my-external-monitor-works-just-fine.37873/#google_vignette) from working, making it harder to recover. I suspect it could even stop the [fan](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1344759/asus-fan-control-not-working-does-not-find-kernel-module) from working, which could damage hardware.

Comment: @DanielT, I renamed the firmware binaries, ran `update-initramfs`, and rebooted. My `dmesg` output and wireless card behavior haven't changed. Do I actually need to move the binaries out of `/lib/firmware`, rather than just renaming them?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I would have just done `sudo mv /lib/firmware/mediatek /root`

Comment: @DanielT, I moved the binaries entirely out of `/lib/firmware/mediatek` (into my home directory), ran `update-initramfs`, and rebooted. Still no change in `dmesg` output or wireless card behavior. This time, I ran `modprobe`; its output *has* changed, saying "Module mt7961e not found in directory /lib/modules/6.5.0-15-generic." I also ran `update-initramfs` verbosely, and I noticed that neither the path `/lib/firmware` nor the string `mt7961e` appears anywhere in the output. (I'd expect the latter to appear, because the module filename is `mt7921e.ko`, and other `.ko` filenames appear.)

Comment: This is strange. I suppose it confirms your suspicion that you "don't think the new binaries are running"